# Castle windsor registration

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

```
interface IUserService
class LocalUserService : IUserService
class RemoteUserService : IUserService

interface IUserRepository
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
```

If I have the following interfaces and classes, where the `IUserService` classes have a dependency on `IUserRepository`. I can register these components by doing something like:

```
container.AddComponent("LocalUserService", typeof(IUserService), typeof(LocalUserService));
container.AddComponent("RemoteUserService", typeof(IUserService), typeof(RemoteUserService));
container.AddComponent("UserRepository", typeof(IUserRepository), typeof(UserRepository));
```

... and get the service I want by calling:

```
IUserService userService = container.Resolve<IUserService>("RemoteUserService");
```

However, if I have the following interfaces and classes:

```
interface IUserService
class UserService : IUserService

interface IUserRepository
class WebUserRepository : IUserRepository
class LocalUserRepository : IUserRepository
class DBUserRepository : IUserRepository
```

How do I register these components so that the `IUserService` component can "choose" which repository to inject at runtime?   My idea is to allow the user to choose which repository to query from by providing 3 radio buttons (or whatever) and ask the container to resolve a new `IUserService` each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to decide which component to inject (push) you use `IHandlerSelector`s.

If you want to decide which component to pull you use TypedFactoryFacility.

and as a sidenote.

Don't use `AddComponent`, use `container.Register(Component.For...)`

Comment: Is there a difference between AddComponent and Register?

Comment: Major difference is that Register is far more flexible, and that `AddComponent` will be obsolete starting with next version, and removed later on.